# Change image size when collapse sidebar jQuery

Tags: jquery, fluid-layout, collapsable

First time trying to do any coding, and was not sure how to make my question presentable without using entire code in jsfiddle.

the html:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header">
    <p id="headtitle">
      <button id="switch">Header Button to close Menu</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar" class="ui-accordion" style="">
```

the js:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#switch")
  .button()
  .click(function(){

      $("#sidebar").toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

the css:

```
#sidebar {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 32.6007%;
    display: block;
}
#map {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 66.3003%;
    display: block;
}
```

my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FcZE/)

when site is in pc mode/larger screen, the sidemenu is to the left of the image. Yet when collapsed, i want the image to fill the entire screen. Did i use the wrong way of collapsing the sidemenu so that the image (map) will fill the screen? My image is just shifting left, instead of resizing how i would like it to.

after looking at the slide in dw, i realized since im using fluid grid layout, that my map div is set at 66.3003%, hence it is not changing to 100%. Is it possible to change the css of the div to 100%? I would still want the layout to remain fluid, so an actual px size wouldn't work i believe.